# ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 getActivity() Never Returns

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-testing

Whenever I run all the tests in my Android Test Project, one of my tests never completes. Using LogCat, I have narrowed the issue down to the `getActivity()` method. I also put `Log.d()` in `ViewAllSongsActivity.onCreate()`, but the message was never printed. When I run `ViewAllSongsActivityTests` by itself, the test passes. Below is the code for the test:

```
public class ViewAllSongsActivityTests extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<ViewAllSongsActivity> {
    public ViewAllSongsActivityTests() {
        super(ViewAllSongsActivity.class);
    }

    public void testSongsAreLoaded() throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, ClassNotFoundException {
        Activity activity = this.getActivity(); // this never returns
        ListView songList = (ListView) activity.findViewById(R.id.allSongsList);
        assertTrue(songList.getCount() > 0);
    }
}
```